# How to achieve the following layout using bootstrap responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: Layout]

so far this is what i have done

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"></div>


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 blog-post1">
    <img src="./assests/1.png" alt="" />
    <div class="overley-nav">
      <input type="button" value="Travel" />
      <h3>The Complete Guide for Travel in London</h3>
      <p>by MARIE NGUYEN / DECEMBER 13,2016</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 blog">

    <div class="blogpost2">
      <img src="./assests/2.png" alt="" />
      <div class="overley-nav2">
        <input type="button" value="Travel" />
        <h4>The Complete Guide</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogpost3">
      <img src="./assests/3.png" alt="" />
      <div class="overley-nav2">
        <input type="button" value="Travel" />
        <h4>The Complete Guide</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1"></div>
</section>
```

here on the above code i have create one section as row and the rest of the div within this section are assign some numbers of columns by using this technique 
my image and text are not adjusting them self as i shrink the browser window.

Comment: It does work tho :-) What is the problem? It shrinks till it gets too small, thus your xs-12, and then it go over multiple lines. Everything in your code works and is doing what you're telling it to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "adjusting them self", Shahroz?

Comment: @andreas i want my text on top of image at the center position but unfortunately my text move around the div it does not stay at one place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width that is as large as the image you're using if you want the text to "stay still". [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/8gy01b3z/).

If you want the image at the bottom of the text, just [put it's div underneath it](https://jsfiddle.net/8gy01b3z/1/).

```css
.overley-nav {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"></div>


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 blog-post1">
    <img src="http://static1.purebreak.com/articles/9/15/82/99/@/629110-grumpy-cat-disaster-girl-doge-que-s-200x200-1.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="overley-nav">
      <input type="button" value="Travel" />
      <h3>The Complete Guide for Travel in London</h3>
      <p>by MARIE NGUYEN / DECEMBER 13,2016</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 blog">

    <div class="blogpost2">
      <img src="http://static1.purebreak.com/articles/9/15/82/99/@/629110-grumpy-cat-disaster-girl-doge-que-s-200x200-1.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="overley-nav">
        <input type="button" value="Travel" />
        <h4>The Complete Guide</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogpost3">
      <img src="http://static1.purebreak.com/articles/9/15/82/99/@/629110-grumpy-cat-disaster-girl-doge-que-s-200x200-1.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="overley-nav">
        <input type="button" value="Travel" />
        <h4>The Complete Guide</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```